# Can't program Arduino 328P after first time use of ICSP Sparkfun AVR Pocket Programmer

Tags: arduino-uno, avrdude

I needed to change my Brown Out Voltage to 4.3V from the Arduino default. I purchased from Sparkfun the AVR Pocket Programmer and connected as instructed. I have an Arduino 328P with CC3000 wifi shield. All worked perfectly before ICSP fuse change. My default fuse settings as read successfully using the AVRDude cmd,

avrdude -c usbtiny -p atmega328p was H=05, L=FF, E=DE.

I ran the following cmd to change on the BOD setting to 4.3,

avrdude -c usbtiny -p atmega328p -U lfuse:w:0xff:m -U hfuse:w:0x05:m -U efuse:w:0xfc:m as instructed using the Engbedded AVR Fuse Calculator. This appeared to run successfully. I was completely unable to program my board after this and could not run the avrdude -c usbtiny -p atmega328p without getting an initialization failed, rc=-1 error.

Killing me too as I was a hair away from launching my project to an organic farm for the first phase of an innovative irrigation control system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully the problem is your connections. Check you connections, and if they isn't the problem, you have some work to do:

After alooked at your fuses, I searched a few things up and saw [this](http://www.codingwithcody.com/2011/04/arduino-default-fuse-settings/). The default fuse values are:

- Low Fuse 0xFF
- High Fuse    0xDE
- Extended Fuse    0x05

You mixed up your fuses above. I used AtmelStudio to check what your fuses would do:

```
avrdude -c usbtiny -p atmega328p -U lfuse:w:0xff:m -U hfuse:w:0x05:m -U efuse:w:0xfc:m
```

This would change the `RSTDISBL` value and enable RSTDISBL. According to the datasheet, doing this will

> Setting the reset disable fuse will cause JTAG and ISP programming to stop working. Can only be unset with
>   high-voltage programming

By doing this, you bricked your chip. Now, you would want to undo this. The only way you could do this for cheap without buying a fancy [STK500](http://www.atmel.com/tools/STK500.aspx) is to buy a new Atmega328p or to use another Arduino Uno to use high-voltage programming to completely erase your bricked one.

In order to do this, follow [this](http://makezine.com/2008/09/25/how-to-use-arduino-as-a-h/) tutorial to erase your chip. This tutorial uses a perfboard, but you can do the same exact thing on the breadboard.

Now once you erase your bricked Arduino, you have to put the correct fuses.

The default ones are:

- Low Fuse 0xFF
- High Fuse    0xDE
- Extended Fuse    0x05

Now, you want to change the Brown-out Voltage to `4.3V` right? Using AtmelStudio, once again, I have come up with the following fuses:

- Low Fuse 0xFF
- High Fuse    0xDE
- Extended Fuse    0x04

Once you program this, you should have a working Arduino!

If you need to program the Arduino using the Arduino software by USB, not by the AVR programmer, you will have to program the bootloader. Reply if you need help with that. That said, if you will always be using the AVR programmer from now, the bootloader may not be necessary.

This will fix your problem and make your brown-out voltage correct!

Always triple check your fuses using something like AtmelStudio, because you could end up doing a lot of extra work like in this case.

Comment: oh man! I was double checking my notes and found my carelessness. I actually had the right starting point, but must have goofed typing it in. Thanks for your advice on maybe fixing this.

Comment: So I purchased a new Arduino Uno to solve my problem above and now, being extra careful, I first read the default values using my Sparkfun AVR Programmer. I received the proper device signature and among other things the line, avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK (H:05, E:DE, L:FF). This is not what I expected based on board.txt file and as echo'd by the learned programmer, @Shiven above. I was expected that read of fuses to echo L:FF, H:DE, E:05. As such I am quite concerned I still don't understand this.

Comment: @DPGUITARMAN there may be something wrong with your programmer. I have an AVRISP mkII and my Arduino reads (E:05, H:DE,L:FF). This is exactly what is in the boards.txt file. What is your command to read the fuses? If that is right, I believe something may be wrong with your programmer.

Comment: Does it work before you checked the fuses? Also, since the programmer programmed the fuses like you told it in the initial question correctly (but you gave it the wrong fuses), you could try programming my fuses above (in the answer), as those fuses cannot mess up your Arduino.

Comment: Here is the command I use to read the fuses. It is from the Sparkfun tutorial for AVRDUDE. avrdude -c usbtiny -p atmega328p. The board did work fine out of the box. I played with the blink test changing the blink rate and all was excellent. After I read the fuses I tried the blink testing again and all worked fine. It doesn't make sense. I will try programming your fuses today and advise.

Comment: @DPGUITARMAN based on what you said there may be something wrong with your programmer. Try programming my uses.

Comment: I programmed with the following cmd: avrdude -c usbtiny -p atmega328p -U efuse:w:0x04:m. AVRdude returned feedback that all was successfully written and reading back efuse, however, at the end it indicated, fuses ok (H:04, E:DE, L:FF). Note that only H changed. It is almost like H and E are reversed in the readback. I plan later on checking that indeed the BOD changed to 4.3 as I have a DC supply I can control. More to come. Taking it ever so carefully as I don't want to brick this device too.

Comment: Does the Arduino still work? You should read the bootloader section above if it does not. (Like a stk:500 out of sync error). But you can check if it is bricked or not by getting the device information again.

Comment: works perfectly after changing the efuse relative to blink test. Just puzzled about the read back of fuse values. I will also verify the BOD is what I think i programmed it to be. Thanks for your support @shiven

Comment: Checked the BOD and it is set correctly. I believe I am good. Thanks for the wisdom @shiven